# pandas monthly offset duplicate index

Tags: python, pandas

i have a time series with dates like so:
    t
    2017-05-30
    2017-05-31

etc...

I want to compute 1 month trailing.  I.e, compare date 2017-05-31 with 1m ago.  I tried this function:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
spy['aum_1m'] = spy['aum_t'].shift(freq=DateOffset(months=1))
```

But this with ]

```
ValueError with "cannot reindex with duplicate axis".
```

I think the reason is because if my time series as two dates: 05/30/2019 and 05/31/2019, 
it shifts both the dates to 06/30/2019 instead of moving the 2nd one to 07/01/2019.  Is there a way to avoid the duplicate index and move to the next good date?  Thanks

Comment: you are right about why, but the question now is if you also have the date 2019-06-01, at which date you want to move it as you want to move 2019-05-31 to 2019-07-01 already? if you want to keep going, then do a offset of 30 or 31 days instead of a month?

Comment: yea that's what i was thinking, doing an offset to 30 to 31 days instead of a month.  is much better